# Share Nodes between projects

Tags: gentics-mesh

Is it possible to share nodes between projects? A kind of global nodes, like icons.

Or is there a concept of subprojects?

I was searching anywhere in the mesh-UI for such an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is currently not possible. There are a few limitations when working with multiple projects:

Not yet supported:

- Moving nodes between projects
- Linking nodes between projects
- Using GraphQL across multiple projects

We plan to add a common `/api/v1/nodes` endpoint which will allow you to load nodes of all projects.